# How to enable an optional build dependency using nix-shell?

Tags: python, opencv, gtk, nix, nixos

I would like to use gtk-enabled opencv with python 3 inside of a nix-shell.

I am able to launch a non-gtk enabled python3/opencv environment with:

```
nix-shell --pure -p python35Packages.opencv3
```

However, commands that open windows fail:

```
[nix-shell:~/src/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/opencv]$ python
Python 3.5.3 (default, Jan 17 2017, 07:57:56) 
[GCC 5.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import cv2
>>> cv2.namedWindow("foo") 
OpenCV Error: Unspecified error (The function is not implemented. Rebuild the library with Windows, GTK+ 2.x or Carbon support. If you are on Ubuntu or Debian, install libgtk2.0-dev and pkg-config, then re-run cmake or configure script) in cvNamedWindow, file /tmp/nix-build-opencv-3.2.0.drv-0/opencv-3.2.0-src/modules/highgui/src/window.cpp, line 565
```

In the package definition in `/nixpkgs/pkgs/development/libraries/opencv/3.x.nix`, there are function parameters `enableGtk2` and `enableGtk3` that switch on the optional dependency in the build.

I read through several nix tutorials and the entire syntax definition for the language.

Switching on an optional dependency is pretty fundamental, so I would expect it to be doable using the command-line tools, i.e. `nix-shell`. Anyone know how it is done?

Answer (score 4):

This is the command that you would need to use in this case:

```
nix-shell -p "python35Packages.opencv3.override { enableGtk2 = true; }"
```

Another solution would be to override the `python35Packages.opencv3` package once and for all as explained in the [nixpkgs documentation](https://nixos.org/nixpkgs/manual/#sec-modify-via-packageOverrides). Then you would be able to use your command unchanged.